# What's the best practice for adding a lot of attributes to a Rails model?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

So, I'm building an API wrapper gem that works with Spree's Product model. The API provides extensive customization of the data you send to it. I would like a user of the gem to be able to take advantage of all the customizations should they desire to. This appears to me as if I should create a migration that adds about 50 new attributes to the Product model in order to allow the user to customize these attributes for a product.

It feels awfully invasive for me to add 50 attributes to a model in which only a few may be used by any given user (it would be an edge case for someone to use most/all of them). What's the best practice for offering these attributes to the user without muddying up the main model.

My thought may have been to create another model that belongs to the Product and contains the API attributes, but this seems like it may create technical overhead.

For example:

```
class Spree::Product
  has_one :spree_product_api_attribute_set
  delegate :attr1, :attr2, :attr3..., to: :spree_product_api_attribute_set
end
```

Comment: This feels like an array, not 50 individual attributes.  Could it be done with an array of attributes?

Comment: @RobertHarvey how do you mean? You mean persist a Hash?

Comment: @RobertHarvey it's certainly feasible, but since I'm using MySQL, I'll lost the ability to query by any of those attributes and will also lose ActiveRecord's built-in validations...\

Comment: Ah, I see.  But are these user-defined attributes?  How do you know what the validations are going to be if you don't know what the attributes are yet?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, they're attributes that the API supports that aren't necessarily native to the engine.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Here are the docs for the API resource. Most of the attributes cannot be inferred from existing Spree attributes. https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/v2/reference/v2/products

Comment: Maybe you would be better off serializing the data and doing the search with something like Elasticsearch. It's easy enough, adds lots of bonus features (full text search one of it) and if the project grows you will use it anyway.

Comment: @thorstenmüller yeah but then I'm adding a large dependency to anyone's stack using the gem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Postgres, HStore or JSON can store key values pretty easily. You can still use indexes to query the DB. If there were 50 attributes that is what I would use. Far superior to serialized fields.